# If statement in react .map function

Tags: reactjs, function, dictionary, conditional-statements

I'm trying to only map a function to listItems if the condition is true, otherwise skip it. I have been trying different stuff but I don't want to return before the list is complete.

I have this code:

```html
    const listItems = (
      <ul>
        {desclist.map((point, index) =>
        if (point.length < 2) {
            <li key={index}>
              <p>{point}</p>
            </li>
          )}
        }
      </ul>
    );

    return listItems;
  }
```

Comment: Check this out : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3rwjh1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return something within the `.map` function, it won't end the loop of the function and will still continue iterating. Instead, what you return will be put within the resulting array that `.map` returns. Meaning that if inside the `.map` you return a component depending on an if statement, and otherwise none, the result will be an array with all the components that were returned.

```
const listItems = (
    <ul>
        {
            desclist.map((point, index) =>
                if (point.length < 2) {
                    return <li key={index}>
                        <p>{point}</p>
                    </li>;
                }
            );
        }
    </ul>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know that. Very nice :)

Answer (score 1):

If else will work under parentheses and also don’t use index directly as key instead append some text along with index to key prop so

Change

```
   {desclist.map((point, index) =>
    if (point.length < 2) {
        <li key={index}>
          <p>{point}</p>
        </li>
      )}
    }
```

To

```
   {desclist.map((point, index) => {
    if (point.length < 2) {
        return (<li key={'Key-'+index}>
          <p>{point}</p>
        </li>
      )}
    }
   )}
```